# docker image still showing in image listing after removing the image from docker

Tags: docker

I have reinstall/upgraded docker on one of my server machines. When I list down the images I get

```
[root@controlnode ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
neo4j                                  3.3.3               6a0065af33a2        5 weeks ago         190MB
boldds/docker_images_premium-service   firsttry            f7c3915d6b00        5 months ago        1.19GB
```

When I tried removing the neo4j image I got this error

```
[root@controlnode ~]# docker rmi neo4j:3.3.3
Error: No such image: neo4j:3.3.3

[root@controlnode ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
neo4j                                  3.3.3               6a0065af33a2        5 weeks ago         190MB
boldds/docker_images_premium-service   firsttry            f7c3915d6b00        5 months ago        1.19GB
```

I also tried `docker system prune -a` but I am still seeing the image in the image listing command `docker images`. How can I clear the docker cache, so that it will not list dangling images.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ID "6a0065af33a2" or the tag you specified "3.3.3" to remove the image like so:

```
docker image rm 6a0065af33a2
```